# Vector representation

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I saw many people representing vectors like this: `----->` in a 2D plane. Why do you need the little arrow head over there in the end? Doesn't it make that a ray and magnitude will hence become infinity? Shouldn't it be represented somewhat like this: `-----`?

Comment: A vector is a quantity with magnitude and direction, so the line segments with arrows make visual sense.

Comment: Why would it make the magnitude become infinity? This is just a symbol we use to denote the line between two points (where usually one of the two is the origin), you cannot read anything like this off of it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not clear, according to what I have been taught in school, line segment with an arrow is called a **ray** which goes on and on in the direction mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segment as $\_\_\_\_\_\_\_$   indicate a direction (the direction of the line that contains the segment) but to specify a vector we need also an orientation on this direction (for a given direction we can have two opposite orientations), so we use an arrow to indicate the orientation.

Comment: Cool I got it now! Basically it means to identify which is the head and which is the tail right? As tail is the one in the same point even when flipped

Comment: Yes, usually the orientation is from tail to head.

Answer (score 1):

A vector in 2D designates a change in position. Given a starting place, it will tell you the ending place. Hence the arrow.

You are free to choose the starting place (unless specified) and if you don't specify the arrow head, there is nothing distinguishing between the two following scenarios

```
(a)----->(b)

(a)<-----(b)
```